# dynamic text added by default to every map document?

Tags: arcmap, dynamic-text

I'd like to have the document path inserted by default on every map (that I can then delete if it's not needed) because I keep losing track of the electronic versions of maps for older ones (ca. 2012) I have printed, and my brain seems far too taxed to remember to add it each time. I have the standard ArcMap license with 10.3.

Answer (score 2):

You can create and save different map templates based on your preferences. Check out the [Using Map Templates](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/using-mxd-templates.htm) help page.

Just add the dynamic text the the mxd, and follow the steps to save it as a template, then use this as your default to always have the path set automatically.